# Joining a list into a string in python

Tags: python, string, list

What is the easiest way to 'split' a list into a string in Python?

To create a list from a string:

```
s='1\t2\t3\t4'
```

we use:

```
s.split('\t',-1)
```

I tried using the split function to a list:

```
l=[1,2,3,4]
```

to get a string:

```
s='1\t2\t3\t4'
```

but I got an `AttributeError` telling that list has no attribute split.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`str.split` is a method that is only available on the `str` type. How it works is explained in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

> `str.split([sep[, maxsplit]])`
>
> Return a list of the words in the string, using `sep` as the delimiter string. If 
>   `maxsplit` is given, at most `maxsplit` splits are
>   done (thus, the list will have at most `maxsplit+1` elements). If
>   `maxsplit` is not specified or `-1`, then there is no limit on the number
>   of splits (all possible splits are made).

---

What you want to use here is `str.join`:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> map(str, l) # Just to demonstrate
['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> '\t'.join(map(str, l))
'1\t2\t3\t4'
>>>
```

According to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

> `str.join(iterable)`
>
> Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in the iterable `iterable`. The separator between elements is the string
>   providing this method.

In the above example, `str.join` takes the list of strings returned by `map(str, l)`:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

and concatenates all of its items together, separating each one by `\t`.  The result is the string:

```
'1\t2\t3\t4'
```

---

Also, in case you are wondering, [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) is being used in the above example to convert the list of integers into a list of strings.  An alternate approach would be to use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> '\t'.join([str(x) for x in l])
'1\t2\t3\t4'
>>>
```

Both solutions are about equivalent, but you need to use one of them because `str.join` requires an iterable of strings.

Comment: Simply using a generator is actually enough here :)

Comment: @SamyArous - Yes, but it is generally less efficient.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/2555451).

Comment: +1 for the inclusion of map and the list comp. A corollary on how to convert back to a list (using `str.split` as OP originally thought he had to do) would be further enlightening.

Comment: @iCodez This is actually very interesting. Thank you for the link :)

Comment: @adsmith - I'm sorry, but I do not know what you mean.  If I am not mistaken, the OP already knows how to convert a string into a list.  He was having trouble going the other way.

Comment: @iCodez It seems to me that OP is confused on how `split` works, since he's trying to do `list.split` to get a string. If I were you, I would add a short note explaining how `str.split` works and mention that it's a method belonging to a `str`, and how it differs from `str.join` in more explicit terms.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
'\t'.join([str(x) for x in l])
```

[join-Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

Comment: That would actually raise a TypeError. You have to cast the integers into strings first

Answer (score 0):

That's not splitting, that's joining: `'\t'.join(str(i)  for i in l)`

Comment: Won't work, a `TypeError` will be raised as you cannot join together integers as they are not iterable. You need to explicitly convert the integers to strings.